# Performant Way to Find/Match Each Item from One List Within Another List

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have two Lists of two separate, but relatable classes.

```
class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

```
class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

For each item in `List<A>`, I need to find its counterpart (`A.Id == B.Id`) in `List<B>`, if it exists, and then update `A.Name` from `B.Name`.

I know how to do this easily enough. For example:

```
List<A>.ForEach(a =>
{
    a.Name = List<B>.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == a.Id)?.Name;
});
```

This is, of course, very slow. I think O(n*m)? And I'm dealing with several million records in each List. I've searched for a better answer, but haven't come across anything directly applicable yet. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A dictionary or hashset will provide faster lookup (`O(1)`)

Comment: @RufusL would that then reduce it down to O(n) if I performed the lookup that way? Not sure how doing that escaped me... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using Dictionary:

*Note: your original example has a.Name being set to NULL when no match found in b list:*

```
var bDictionary = bList.ToDictionary(b => b.Id);

foreach (var a in aList)
{
    bDictionary.TryGetValue(a.Id, out var b);
    a.Name = b?.Name;
}
```

Comment: And this is O(n), or at least very close, right (besides the `.ToDictionary` operation)? Since we still have to iterate through each item in `List<A>`, but the lookup should be close to O(1)?

Comment: List B is iterated to build dictionary. List A iterated to do lookups. Lookup is O(1).